# Python Texttable - Total width for each row

Tags: python

Is there a method to determine the column width for the Table after the rows have been added.
For example even if I set initialization parameters below:

```
 text_table = Texttable( max_width= 160)
```

The table may default to a smaller size if the row's total width is less than the number, which is a good rendering.
However, I would like to know what was the actual width for the entire row, in the case of rows where the width does not hit the max_width limit.

Comment: Based on the implementation, the row widths are available in text_table._width after a call to draw.

Answer (score 0):

The solution text_table.width returns a list of numbers but the sum does not equate the table width.

Using the following accurately returns.

```
table_width = max( [ len(x) for x in table_as_str.split('\n') ])
```

where table_as_str is the result from  text_table.draw()

Thanks